# Get a ton of errors when using bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am totaly new to ruby and have been using a tutorial that guided me through adding some gems to the Gemfile of my project. GEMFILE:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails' 

group :test, :development do 
  gem 'turn'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'growl_notify'

end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

I then went on to my terminal, ran bundle install and got a bunch of errors. Like a ton so I don't want to add them all, but I will add a few.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
creating Makefile

make
compiling src/rbae.c
src/rbae.c:13:27: error: Carbon/Carbon.h: No such file or directory
src/rbae.c:14:43: error: CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/rbae.c:15:
src/SendThreadSafe.h:73:53: error: ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/rbae.c:15:
src/SendThreadSafe.h:125: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SendMessageThreadSafe’
src/rbae.c:24: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘AEDesc’
src/rbae.c:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘upp_GenericEventHandler’
src/rbae.c:39: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘upp_GenericCoercionHandler’
src/rbae.c:61: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘OSErr’
src/rbae.c: In function ‘rbAE_raiseMacOSError’:
src/rbae.c:66: error: ‘number’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/rbae.c:66: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
src/rbae.c:66: error: for each function it appears in.)
src/rbae.c: At top level:
src/rbae.c:89: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rbStringToDescType’
src/rbae.c:99: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘descType’
src/rbae.c: In function ‘rbAE_freeAEDesc’:
src/rbae.c:112: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘AEDisposeDesc’
src/rbae.c:112: error: ‘struct rbAE_AEDescWrapper’ has no member named ‘desc’
src/rbae.c: At top level:
src/rbae.c:117: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘AEDesc’
src/rbae.c:117: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
src/rbae.c:138: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘AEDesc’
src/rbae.c:138: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
src/rbae.c: In function ‘rbAE_AEDesc_new’:
src/rbae.c:153: error: ‘OSErr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/rbae.c:153: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘err’
src/rbae.c:154: error: ‘AEDesc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/rbae.c:154: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘desc’
src/rbae.c:157: error: ‘err’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/rbae.c:157: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘AECreateDesc’
src/rbae.c:157: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rbStringToDescType’
src/rbae.c:159: error: ‘desc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/rbae.c:160: error: ‘noErr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/rbae.c:160: error: too many arguments to function ‘rbAE_raiseMacOSError’
src/rbae.c:161: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rbAE_wrapAEDesc’
src/rbae.c: In function ‘rbAE_AEDesc_newList’:
src/rbae.c:168: error: ‘OSErr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/rbae.c:168: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘err’
src/rbae.c:169: error: ‘AEDesc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

How can i get past these? With my limited knowledge it seems as though there are errors in the ruby files I installed... But could be way off.

MY RAILS -V:

```
Rails 3.2.9

ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
```

Comment: If anyone thinks its necessary that I add all the errors I will, I just didn't want to add too much...

Comment: Can you show the whole Gemfile? It looks like you're missing a gem dependency

Comment: can you paste your ruby, rails and bundler version? What happen if you just install each gem via terminal. e.g; `gem install trun`

Comment: Which gem gave you all these errors?? Did these errors pop up right after you did `bundle install` or you got it when it came down to a certain gem?